# JNI needs to load a DSO on linux which its name does not start with lib

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I searched for an answer to this issue (here and at other sites), and I did not find a suitable solution. So I post the question here:

I need to wrap some C code with Java class, using JNI on linux.
The C dso name on linux is at_base.so and not **lib**at_base.so, this is from historical reasons, and I prefer not to change the dso name, though I've inserted some new methods to be used by the the Java class (as native methods called by JNI).
I've tried to load the dso using the full dso path like this:

```
{
    File f = new File("/opt/my_company/my_product/lib/at_base.so");
    System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile() + " exists = " + f.exists() );
    System.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Running it shows the dso at_base.so do exist, but loading it fails giving UnsatisfiedLink error. There is no path issue here, as if I add a symbolic link **lib**at_base.so which points to at_base.so (at the same /opt/.../lib directory), this solves the problem. It seems that though I supply the full path of the dso to java "/opt/my_company/my_product/lib/at_base.so", it still tries to load **lib**at_base.so from the given path.

My question is: is there a way to tell Java to load the dso giving it the exact name, without being forced to have the library name starts with **lib**.

Comment: Using `System.load` actually *should* work (because it does not do the magic lookup that is done with `loadLibrary`) - it should really only load the file. So to be sure: How does it work when you copy/rename the library to `libat_base.so`? Do you then call `System.load(.../at_base.so"` or `System.load(.../libat_base.so"`? Are you sure that there is **no** hidden `System.loadLibrary` call somewhere else? What does the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` say exactly?

Comment: What historical reasons? If it ever worked, it should still work, and it if never worked there is no reason to leave it non-working. If it was previously just a C or C++ only DSO, write *another* one containing your JNI methods, and conforming to the required naming conventions, that links to it,

Comment: Yep, I see I did have another call to System.loadLibrary( "at_base") which I somehow missed, and this caused Java to search for libat_base.so (which it did not find). 
When I use System.load with full path, it really loads at_base.so, and all works fine. Thanks